# Button from view to call a controller action to update database column

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add users to an array in a table column (PostgreSQL) when a button is clicked. The button click registers but the controller method is not called and no error is given.

I have the following view with the button in it.

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(Pairing.new, url: users_path, method: :patch, html: { id: 'my_special_form' }) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :supervisor_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:supervisor_id, User.where(role: 1), :id, :name) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :student_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:student_id, User.where(role: 0), :id, :name) %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And the javascript in another file.

assets/javascripts/pair.js

```
$("#my_special_form").submit(function(){

  var url = this.action + "/" + this.elements["pairing[student_id]"].value;

  $.ajax(url, {
    beforeSend: $.rails.CSRFProtection,
    data: {
      user: {
        supervisor_id: this.elements["pairing[supervisor_id]"].value
      }
    }
    type: 'PATCH',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log('Success', data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    }
  });

  return false; // cancels out the normal form submission
});
```

I'm trying to call this method in the controller

controllers/users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  def index
    @users = User.all
    authorize User
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize user
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end

  def pair
    supervisor = User.find(params[:id1])
    student = User.find(params[:id2])

    studentlist = supervisor.select(:supervised_students)
    studentlist << student.
    supervisor.update_attribute(:supervised_students => studentlist)
    @supervisor.save
  end

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role)
  end

end
```

add_supervisor migration

```
class AddSupervisor < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :supervisor_id, :integer
  end
end
```

user model

```
enum role: [:student, :supervisor, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  has_many :students, class_name: "Users",
                      foreign_key: "supervisor_id"

  belongs_to :supervisor, class_name: "User"

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :student
  end
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources  :users

  resources  :pairings

  resources  :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
    member do
      post :reply
    end
  end

  resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
    member do
      post :restore
    end
  end

  resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
    collection do
      delete :empty_trash
    end
  end

  resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
    member do
      post :mark_as_read
    end
  end

  resources  :messages, only: [:new, :create]

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'pages#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'pages#welcome', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end



  root to: 'pages#index'

end
```

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: I think I've already managed to send the data to javascript from the view. My issue i believe is sending the data from the javascript to my controller action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` in URI's is used for is used for the fragment identifier - it is transparent to the server by specification.

So when you send the ajax request its actually interpreted as `POST /users`.

`root` is used to set the handler for the `/` path. If you want to add `POST users/pair` you would do

```
resources :users do
   collection do
     post 'pair', to: "users#pair"
   end
end
```

Note that `#` in routes means `controller#action` and has nothing to do with the result

However this is how I would approach the problem instead.

### Set up the relations

Make sure you have a `supervisor_id` column on `users`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, class_name: "Users",
                      foreign_key: "supervisor_id"

  belongs_to :supervisor, class_name: "User"
end
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

### Setting up the route

In this case you might want to consider if you really need a special route at all. Especially since you are using ajax.

In fact if you want to assign a student to supervisor all you really need is a PATCH request.

```
PATCH /users/5 { supervisor_id: 6 }
```

### The form

If you where simply listing the students you could use a simple form like this and you would be good to go:

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :supervisor, User.where(role: 1) %> 
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

However if you want to have two selects you need to set the ajax request URL dynamically. We are going to use a little trick to be able to use the form helpers properly:

```
# app/models/pairing
class Pairing
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :supervisor_id, :student_id
end
```

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model

This is a model that is not backed by a database table. We can simply use it to bind the form
inputs:

```
<%= form_for(Pairing.new, url: users_path, method: :patch, html: { id: 'my_special_form' }) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :supervisor_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:supervisor_id, User.where(role: 1), :id, :name) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :supervisor_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:student_id, User.where(role: 0), :id, :name) %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This form is not going to work off the bat since it would PATCH to `/users`. 
What we want to do is alter the url to to point to the currect user when the form is submitted.

```
$("#my_special_form").submit(function(){

  var url = this.action + "/" + this.elements["pairing[student_id]"].value;

  $.ajax(url, {
    beforeSend: $.rails.CSRFProtection,
    data: {
      user: {
        supervisor_id: this.elements["pairing[supervisor_id]"].value
      }
    },
    type: 'PATCH',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log('Success', data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    }
  });

  return false; // cancels out the normal form submission
});
```

Comment: I'm currently trying it the way you explained, however in the user model you have used has_many relationships. My student role users can only have 1 supervisor related to them so should i change the relevant ones to has_one instead? Thanks for the detailed answer btw !

Comment: Ah cr*p I was guessing it was many to many from the way you form looked. Going to edit the answer.

Comment: Want to be able to pair a supervisor with many students but a student can only have 1 supervisor. I've put the form you've provided into my users/index.html.erb file but it gave an "undefined method `local_assigns'" error. Does it have to be placed in the pairings/_form.html.erb directory to function ? Thanks again :)

Comment: Its still not going to wok since it was built around a many to many relation. I'm working on on a edit.

Comment: Once i click the pair button it links me to my user profile page saying 1 error prohibited this user from being saved (devise user view). On the chrome console it shows the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" pointing at the "type: 'PATCH'," line in the javascript file. Editing my original question with the current code.

Comment: Ah. Missed a comma after the closing parens for data. Sorry, should have actually tested it.

Comment: Oh I didn't even spot that. Its not giving any errors on the console this time which is great but its routing me to the Edit User page afterwards with Current Password Can't be blank message. Assuming its got something to do with devise, I used a workaround by disabling password confirmation but the supervisor_id field is still empty in the database after viewing it with a db browser app. I believe the javascript isn't executing properly as no Success message is given either. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: For some reason the button doesn't link to the javascript at all

Comment: I would check that the selector works `console.log($('#whatever_your_form_id'))` and also make sure you are running this at document.ready or on `page:change` if you are using turbolinks

Comment: I've worked around it by placing it in script headers in the view. However because I'm using devise i think it is messing with my routes and making the patch request use the update method that is used to update profile info like name email etc.

Comment: I've got it to work and now it updates the supervisor_id column like I wanted it to. However in the console it still gives the error "PATCH http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)" even though it changes the column. And on the pairings table no new pairings get created, it is empty.